# Telegram chat and welcome message

Tags: chat, telegram, php-telegram-bot

Could you tell me how to create welcome message in telegram chat, which visible only for invited user(newbie).
Now bot is created and invited in group. When to login "newbie", chat-bot send welcome-message(for all users).

```
$chat = $message['chat'];
                $user = $message['from'];
                if (isset($message['new_chat_members'])) {
                    $mess_id = $this->send_message('Welcome '. $user['first_name'] , $chat);
                }
```

How i can do this welcome message visible only for a newbie ?
PS: sorry for my english.(

Comment: You can't, there have no such method